# How to set a Resource Pool as the root object for a user logged into VMware vSphere vCenter?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

VMware vSphere 5.5 deployment.  Resource Pool present.  Active Directory LDAP used as identity source for SSO.  Custom role created for specific AD group (RP1_Admin) to manage VMs inside of a resource pool.

Is there a setting to ensure that when users who are in RP1_Admin log in through the web interface those users are immediately dropped into a view that has the resource pool as root object and shows the VMs within the resource pool?

Specifically I would like to avoid displaying the host information.

Currently, if users use the vSphere web client to log into vCenter, then users are dropped into the default view and have to navigate from the vCenter server to the Data Center to the Host down to the Resource Pool.  This is undesirable.

Comment: Create a folder for permissions.